# How to do a GridView with two crossAxisCount in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[This is the example of expected output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6-E0gGKwi3Hb0NHAYMC3bldAUNuHE6e/view?usp=sharing)

For the first row, the crossAxisCount will be 3 and the second row, the crossAxisCount will be 2.

```
GridView.builder(
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                                      childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                                    ),
                                    itemCount: int.parse(snapshot.data.result[num].collected),
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int i) {
                                      return Image.asset(
                                          'assets/coin.png');
                                    }),
```

Comment: Why not just  use two `GridView`?

Comment: Hi, @zionpi! How to do that? I want to display based on itemCount: int.parse(snapshot.data.result[num].collected). If the length is 10, then, I want to display it like 3, 2, 3, 2 pattern for each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `crossAxisCount` to `1` and `childAspectRatio` to number you need, I use 2 
In `itemBuilder` check index is `Odd` and return `Row` with 2 or 3 asset icon 
You can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1, childAspectRatio: 2),
        itemCount: _icons.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index.isOdd) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(flex: 1, child: InfiniteGridView()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfiniteGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InfiniteGridViewState createState() => new _InfiniteGridViewState();
}

class _InfiniteGridViewState extends State<InfiniteGridView> {
  List<IconData> _icons = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _retrieveIcons();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1, childAspectRatio: 2),
        itemCount: _icons.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index.isOdd) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        });
  }

  void _retrieveIcons() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200)).then((e) {
      setState(() {
        _icons.addAll([
          Icons.ac_unit,
          Icons.airport_shuttle,
          Icons.all_inclusive,
          Icons.beach_access,
          Icons.cake,
          Icons.free_breakfast
        ]);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @chunhunghan! Excuse me. Actually, I want the index to be count horizontally in 3, 2 pattern. I have updated a more clear expected output complete with index.

Comment: The above code prompt output like 00, 111, 22, 333, 44..... But actually, I want it to be 012, 34, 567, 89 orientation. Thank you.